# What if I don't have domain name that we pass with link parameter for Firebase dynamic links

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to create firebase dynamic links manually but I didn't understand which domain should I provide for 'link' parameter as shown below:

"https://YourDynamicLinkIdentifier.app.goo.gl/link=https://example.com?offer="+myOfferVar+"&apn=com.your.apn";

Here link = www.example.com but I don't have any domain and I am not intended to pass any.
I am just trying to pass a variable with this link so that the end user can receive the passed variable by clicking on the created dynamic link.

I am really stuck with this. Please help me with this.

Comment: What would you want to happen if users clicked on your dynamic link on a non-mobile device?

Comment: Nothing just redirect him to the play store of browser version.